# iPhone Frame with margins from the default SingleView project created by Xamarin from Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Every time I create new Xamarin project 'iPhone SingleView app' from Visual Studio I'm getting black borders around my frame and have no ability to resize it:

[image]

File by file I compared with the Xamarin Studio project which works just fine.
It turned out that all I need to do is to create Resources folder, put there default splashscreen file:

> Default-568h@2x.png

and include it as a bundle resource.

[image]

I even don't need to specify this image as launching image!

Who can explain the reason of this behavior and why I wasn't able to resize my frame to fill the screen?

Here you can find sample of detault project create from Visual Studio: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/SingleView8.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, this (the presence of `Default-568h@2x.png`) is the obscure method Apple uses to determine if your app supports a 4" display.

Comment: it's weird. Do you have any links?

Comment: http://redth.codes/get-your-monotouch-apps-ready-for-iphone-5-today/

"The way that iOS6 determines if your app is Tall compatible or not is by looking for a specifically sized and named image file for your splash/default screen. The name of this file is:

Default-568h@2x.png"